# Copy from one datasource to another in grails 2

Tags: grails

I'm trying to use a domain that's configured for two datasources to copy data from one datasource to another.  The documentation implies that this is straight-forward but I can only get it to save to the default datasource.

```
class LocalTransaction {
  static mapping = {
    datasources(['DEFAULT','migration'])
  }
}
```

First I tried finding the transaction from the default datasource via LocalTransaction.findAllBy..(), then attempt to save changes via tr.migration.save(flush:true,failOnError:true) but the changes are saved to DEFAULT.

I think tried to create a new instance via LocalTransaction.migration.get(lt.id), copy the data over and then save, but that isn't saving to the migration datasource either.

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.0 has added support for multiple datasources to its core (this was formerly provided by a plugin). Please read the following section in the Grails documentation http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

To save data in a specific datasource, you have to use its name before calling the save() closure, for example:

```
localTransactionObj.migration.save()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but as my question stated, I used that method.